# Loading bitmaps into memory in compressed form in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, image-compression

I've programmed an Android game in the past and had always run into memory issues because my images have been quite large ~(1000x400 px each). I'm now wondering if it is necessary to load images into memory solely as bitmaps. Is there any reason for not loading bitmaps in some loss-less compressed format?

I don't know much at all about image compression/decompression efficiency, but I assume that there would be performance issues. But I feel as though "simple" compression algorithms can't be too processor intensive, even if they only cut down the image to half of it's uncompressed memory footprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that at some level you must have pixel by pixel representation of the image, hence you **must** have a bitmap.

Comment: There are no algorithms that allow you to request a pixel for use like this: compressedImage.getPixel(x,y) and have some sort of decompression lookup for the given pixel?

Comment: They could exist but they will be horribly inefficient. Invoking a method for each pixel would be incredibly slow! Additionally the OS itself would need to represent the image as a Bitmap for the OS to draw it.

Comment: Well I'm imagining something like this (albeit this is a extreme example): the compression algorithm finds that there are only 256 different colors in the bitmap. It creates a lookup table and then uses only the 8 bits necessary for each pixel to find it's actual value in the table. Now the lookup will barely effect the speed and the memory can be compressed greatly.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this is to switch to a compressed graphics type that can be used by OpenGL, as answered on gamedev.stackexchange.com at thsi question:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/28463/8126

Unfortunately for me I have no experience in OpenGL.